# Weibel exercise 1.2.2.: kernels, monics, and monomorphisms are the same in $R$-Mod.

Tags: category-theory, modules, homological-algebra

See image below.  I just want help proving that *all kernels in $R$-Mod are monics*.

> [image]

My attempt:

Let $f : A \to B$ be a map in $R$-Mod.   Suppose $i$ is a kernel of $f$, that is: $fi = 0$ and if $fj = 0$ for any other map $j : A'\to A$ then there is a unique map $g: A' \to A$ such that $j = ig$.

Comment: I think the kernel of a morphism , in the $\mathcal{A}$, is not just a morphism $\iota$, as it has been defined, it is a pair $(A,\iota)$ with the given property(in the definition).

Comment: But anyway, [this](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~ums/pdf/Rankeya_R-mod_and_Abelian_Categories.pdf) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** There are two maps fitting into an appropriate diagram for $0: A'\to B$.